# Navigation component doesn't open the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

guys I'm trying to learn the new way to open fragments, Navigation Component, but I'm facing the next problem:

```
fun navigateToLoading(){
    val action = LoadingFragmentDirections.actionLoadingFragmentToListItemsFragment()
    navController.navigate(R.id.loadingFragment)
}

fun navigateToListPlayers(){
    val action = ListItemsFragmentDirections.actionListItemsFragmentToDetailFragment()
    navController.navigate(action)
}
```

If I use the way of navigateToLoading the fragment is opened right, but If I use navigateToListPlayers with the val action, it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
navController.navigate(R.id.loadingFragment) --> WORK
navController.navigate(action) ----------------> DOESN'T
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this set-up in your module's gradle?

groovy

```
plugins {
  id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

.kts

```
plugins {
   id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}
```

and in your gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

You may also want to check the official docs: [Navigate to a destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate)

Comment: I had this... id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' without kotlin